# How can I split my user String and arrange them in column and rows given the Split Size?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm almost done with this activity, I just need to arrange them in columns and rows given the user's split size and I'm stuck with an output that prints only strings itself. This is my code so far.

```
    Scanner lagoScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter String:");
    String letters = lagoScan.next();



    final int numInLetters = letters.length(); // converted string to number length

    System.out.println("Enter Split Size:");
    int splitSize = lagoScan.nextInt();




    if (numInLetters % splitSize == 0) {

    System.out.println("The Given String is: "+letters);
    System.out.println("The Split String are:");

    //My Split here

    String []in_array;

    in_array = letters.split(""); //Note this there is no delimiter 
    for(int k=0; k < in_array.length; k++){


       System.out.print(" "+in_array[k]);

    }


    // Split ENdss
    }

    else {
    System.out.println("Given input is not divisible by input size.");
    }

}
```

This is the output that I'm trying to follow 
[image]

Comment: Are you just looking to split into groups of 3?

Comment: No, given split size for example is "5" the string will column itself into 5 columns and group itself in rows. That's why I put divisible by user statement and sadly I' m stuck please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= inArray.length; i++) {
  // print the current char.
  System.out.print(inArray[i - 1]);

  // if it's over the split size then print a line break
  // for split size = 3
  // i = 1 - print the char, i = 2, print the char, i = 3, print the char + line break
  if (i % splitSize == 0) {
   System.out.println();
  }

}
```